# Wordpress is giving Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "php" error for pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a wordpress website by developing custom theme in php 7.
I gives me an error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "php" in /srv/disk4/3904345/www/websitename.atwebpages.com/wp-content/themes/customtheme/team-template.php:1

When I updated to the php 8, The error remains.
My code is:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Team Archive
Template Post Type: page
*/ 
?>
<?php get_header();?>
  <Content here>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Can you help me resolve this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Code seems fine. make sure there is no space before and after php tag

Comment: I have checked it. No spaces after tags. Still getting the error. for php 7, the error shows but the page is displayed and for php 8 only the error is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue after updating to PHP 8.0,
and it was actually caused by a single line comment (`//`) in `<?php` `?>` tags, e.g.:

```php
<?php //echo esc_html__( 'Powered by ', 'test' ); ?>
```